# Get the target url from the login page

Tags: spring, spring-security

Is there a way to get the "cached" target url from the login jsp page if that login page is displayed because the user typed the url of a page that requires authentication?
I need to know if the login page is displayed because the user typed the url of the login page directly or if the login page is displayed because the previous page requires authentication.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is how to do with Spring 3.x:

```
SavedRequest savedRequest = new HttpSessionRequestCache().getRequest(request, response)
```

which is null if there is no redirect, if not null, to get the url:

```
savedRequest.getRedirectUrl()
```